# How do you read a cell's value from an OpenOffice Calc .ods file?

Tags: python, ods

I have been able to read an Excel cell value with xlrd using column and row numbers as inputs.  Now I need to access the same cell values in some spreadsheets that were saved in .ods format.

So for example, how would I read with Python the value stored in cell E10 in an  .ods file?

Comment: Some hints and a little code are at http://solyaris.wordpress.com/2007/07/06/reading-open-document-with-python/ It looks like it shouldn't be too, too hard (once you hack your way through XML.

Comment: @msw: *Looks* like it shouldn't be too hard ... but that blogger hasn't been heard from since (almost 3 years ago) ;-)

Comment: Can you depend on openoffice being installed?  The OOo API has python bindings.  Although the API is a bit bewildering, using it is bound to be more reliable than hacking the xml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hacking your way through the XML **shouldn't** be too hard ... but there are complications. Just one example: OOo in their wisdom decided not to write the cell address explicitly. There is no cell attribute like `address="E10"` or `column="E"`; you need to count rows and columns.

Five consecutive empty cells are represented by
`<table:table-cell table:number-columns-repeated="5" />`

The `number-colums-repeated` attribute defaults to "1" and also applies to non-empty cells.

It gets worse when you have merged cells; you get a `covered-table-cell` tag which is 90% the same as the `table-cell` tag, and attributes `number-columns-spanned` and `number-rows-spanned` need to be figured into column and row counting.

A `table:table-row` tag may have a `number-rows-repeated` attribute. This can be used to repeat the contents of a whole non-empty row, but is most often seen when there are more than 1 consecutive empty rows.

So, even if you would be satisfied with a "works on my data" approach, it's not trivial.

You may like to look at [ODFpy](http://opendocumentfellowship.com/projects/odfpy). Note the second sentence: """Unlike other more convenient APIs, this one is essentially an abstraction layer just above the XML format.""" There is an ODF-to-HTML script which (if it is written for ODS as well as for ODT) may be hackable to get what you want.

If you prefer a "works on almost everybody's data and is supported and has an interface that you're familiar with" approach, you may need to wait until the functionality is put into `xlrd` ... but this isn't going to happen soon.

Comment: Given that two supposedly working libraries (pyexcel-ods, odfpy) died on the first file that I tested and third (ezodf) may silently return bogus data I would prefer to avoid writing my own processing. It would sooner or later run into some arcane and mysterious part of .ods file format - like these existing solutions.

Answer (score 2):

From libraries that I tried [ezodf](https://pythonhosted.org/ezodf/) was the one that worked.

```
from ezodf import opendoc, Sheet
doc = opendoc('test.ods')
for sheet in doc.sheets:
   print sheet.name
   cell = sheet['E10']
   print cell.value
   print cell.value_type
```

pyexcel-ods [crashed](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-ods/issues/6), odfpy [crashed](https://github.com/eea/odfpy/issues/28) and in addition its documentation is either missing or horrible.

Given that supposedly working libraries died on the first file that I tested I would prefer to avoid writing my own processing as sooner or later it would either crash or what worse fail silently on some weirder situation.

EDIT: It gets worse. ezodf may [silently return bogus data](https://github.com/T0ha/ezodf/issues/12).

Comment: Thanks for bringing the serious issue with `ezodf` to my attention [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29497292/1391441). Your edit was rejected, but I updated the answer and added the info as a comment. I've personally have a great experience using `pyexcel-ods`.

Comment: @Gabriel And in case of this crash pyexcel-ods is innocent. Problem is caused by bug in LibreOffice (https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97631). Just my bad luck that I triggered some edge case.

Comment: thanks a lots after using ozodf, I realize odfpy was wost of all, if you try to open huge file it just hung for time eating lots of CPU.